# Whats wrong with this IF Statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to get it to display the correct things. When I run it, the hotel cost stays at $960, and if I choose Cairo it will show $0 for the Airline Tickets, and the hotel is $960. The others work fine but wont change the hotel cost from $960.

```
if ($destination == "Barcelona")

    $airFare = 875;
    $hotel = 85 * $numNights;

    if ($destination == "Cairo")
    $airfare = 950;
    $hotel = 98 * $numNights;

    if ($destination == "Rome")
    $airFare = 875;
    $hotel= 110 * $numNights;

    if ($destination == "Santiago")
    $airFare = 820;
    $hotel = 85 * $numNights;

    if ($destination == "Tokyo")
    $airFare = 1575;
    $perNight = 240;

    $tickets = $numTravelers * $airFare;
    $hotel = $numTravelers * $numNights * $perNight;
    $totalCost = $tickets + $hotel;

    print("<p>Destination: $destination<br />");
    print("Number of people: $numTravelers<br />");
    print("Number of nights: $numNights<br />");
    print("Airline Tickets: $".number_format($tickets, 2)."<br />");
    print("Hotel Charges: $".number_format($hotel, 2)."</p>");
    print("<p><strong>TOTAL COST: $".number_format($totalCost, 2)."</strong></p>");
```

Comment: Use {} to block the code, if you aren't using them only the next line will be part of the if-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems:

- Cardinal sin: you're using brace-less `if` statements without indentation, so it's unclear what your intent is. To be safe: **always use braces with `if` unless it's all on a single line!** This is what caused Apple's critical OpenSSL bug earlier this year.
- `$numNights` is undefined, and undefined numbers default to `0` in PHP. And any product of zero is... zero. Hence why your your calculations are coming out wrong when they involve `$numNights`.
- You've embedded the `$` character in double-quoted strings, which means PHP will attempt to parse those strings for variable names. Either escape the symbol by using `\$` or use single-quote strings.

Comment: Why is it coming out to $960 instead of 0? EDIT: FIXED IT. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$destination = "Cairo";
$numNights = (int)10;
$airFare = (int)1000;
$numTravelers = (int)2;
$perNight = (int)49;

if ($destination == "Barcelona")
{
    $airFare = 875;
    $hotel = 85 * $numNights;
}

if ($destination == "Cairo")
{
    $airfare = 950;
    $hotel = 98 * $numNights;
}

if ($destination == "Rome")
{
    $airFare = 875;
    $hotel= 110 * $numNights;
}

$tickets = $numTravelers * $airFare;
$hotel = $numTravelers * $numNights * $perNight;
$totalCost = $tickets + $hotel;

print("<p>Destination: $destination<br />");
print("Number of people: $numTravelers<br />");
print("Number of nights: $numNights<br />");
print("Airline Tickets: $".number_format($tickets, 2)."<br />");
print("Hotel Charges: $".number_format($hotel, 2)."</p>");
print("<p><strong>TOTAL COST: $".number_format($totalCost, 2)."</strong></p>");
```

?>